# PySpark DataFrame imputing nulls based on user-defined functions / window

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I'm trying to impute some missing values based off the following DataFrame.

```
╔═══════╦═════╦═════╦══════╗
║ Group ║  X  ║  Y  ║Res   ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═════╬══════╣
║ a     ║ 100 ║ 100 ║ Null ║
║ a     ║ 200 ║ 100 ║ 50   ║
║ a     ║ 150 ║ 500 ║ 30   ║
║ b     ║ 100 ║ 110 ║ 4    ║
║ b     ║  95 ║  95 ║ Null ║
╚═══════╩═════╩═════╩══════╝
```

If a Res-value is null, I'd like to impute the Null value with the Res-value from the closest other row (defined by Euclidean Distance using X, Y columns) that is in the same group. My desired dataframe is thus

```
╔═══════╦═════╦═════╦══════╗
║ Group ║  X  ║  Y  ║Res   ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═════╬══════╣
║ a     ║ 100 ║ 100 ║ 50   ║
║ a     ║ 200 ║ 100 ║ 50   ║
║ a     ║ 150 ║ 500 ║ 30   ║
║ b     ║ 100 ║ 110 ║ 4    ║
║ b     ║  95 ║  95 ║ 4    ║
╚═══════╩═════╩═════╩══════╝
```

I'm guessing Window functions are a way of doing this but I'm pretty new to Spark and not sure how to go about writing the expression.

Comment: that would mean you have to compute the Euclidean distance between X and Y of null column, against all the other X and Y in the window group? like  (100,100) with (200,100), (100,100) with (150,500), and then find which is closer ?

Comment: and is it possible to have more than one null value in Res per group?

Comment: yes both those are correct. If theres more than 1 null value per Res group I would return the closest distance that has a non-null Res